# How can I make the height of a barplot dependent on the value of a function on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart and a line plot on the same graph, as you can see it in the first (uppermost) figure.

My intention is to add one extra functionality. Whenever the red area lies entirely below the red line, I would like to show the horizontal projection of that area on the red line and color that part in purple, as you can see it in the second figure.

However, no matter how I tried, I encountered the following issues:

- How to color precisely until the red curve without any visible overlap?
- How to make everything below the area of interest transparent? (In this case, no purple coloring should exist below y=0.70.)

The closest I could get was adding an extra purple bar as illustrated in the last figure. (Note: the dashed line and the brown arrow are not plotted by R, I added them in Paint for easier visibility and explanation.) So, my "emergency" idea was to divide the interval corresponding to the little triangle (pointed by the brown arrow) to *many* sub-intervals (let's say 20-30) and add one purple bar to each of the sub-intervals in such a way that they fill up the area *until* the red line entirely, at least *visibly*. Although it's a very-very inelegant workaround.

But it still doesn't help me with the second issue, i.e. how to make the purple area below the dashed line transparent; although I begin to wonder whether that is even feasible.

```
library(ggplot2)

equation <- function(x) {
  1 - 0.01 * x
}
inv_equation <- function(y) {
  (1-y)/0.01
}

x1 <- 0:44


dat <- data.frame(
  class = rep(c("top", "bottom"), each = length(x1)),
  type = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 39)),
  dat_x = rep(x1, 2),
  dat_y = c(c(rep(0.70, 6), rep(0.45, 39)), rep(0.05, length(x1))),
  dat_eq = rep(equation(x1), 2)
)

y2   <- rep(0.75, floor(inv_equation(0.75)-5))
dat2 <- data.frame(x=6:inv_equation(0.75), y=y2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = dat_x, y = dat_y)) +
  geom_bar(data = dat2, aes(x=x, y=y), width = 1, fill = "purple", stat = "identity") +
  geom_col(aes(fill = class), width = 1) + 
  geom_line(data = cbind(dat["dat_x"], dat["dat_y"]), aes(x=rep(x1,2), y=rep(equation(x1), 2)), colour = "red", size = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gregor, please see my edit, I added the minimal reproducible example. The sample data for the bars is practically a bunch of identical values only, and the function's slope parameter is modifiable, and as the user modifies it, so is the purple area supposed to get larger or smaller.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input @Gregor. Indeed there was no need for so many data frame initializations. I got rid of them and simplified that part of the code, as well as the `unlist` and `lapply` functions are removed. I edited the question with the new code.

Comment: Okay, now some clarifying questions. You say initially, *"Whenever the yellow area lies entirely below the red line, I would like to show the projection of that area and color it in, say, purple"*. Your attempts seem to focus on only the area above x = 10. Is this what you want? Or do you want *all* area below the red line and above yellow bars to be purple? It would be helpful if you could show, in Paint, what is your goal.

Comment: I simplified it a bit more and added new photos. You can see my goal in the second figure. Only that tiny area that is located in the same line with the red area should be colored in purple. So nothing above, nothing below and nothing below the red line either.

Comment: Great work! I've been traveling and haven't had time to work on it. Glad you got it worked out!

Comment: Thank you for all your help and nudges towards simplifying and better explaining the problem, @Gregor. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay eventually it turned out not to be that hard, I managed to solve it by myself. I used the `geom_polygon()` function from `ggplot2` whose aesthetics parameter gets the `x` and `y` coordinates of the four vertices of the trapezoid. These coordinates can be computed automatically from the `inv_equation()` function.

The code is as follows (I didn't need to change any of the previous code):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = dat[1:45,], aes(x=dat["dat_x"]$dat_x[1:45], 
                                  y=dat["dat_y"]$dat_y[1:45]+dat[46:90,]$dat_y), 
           width = 1, fill = "#F8766D", stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = dat[1:45,], aes(x=dat["dat_x"]$dat_x[1:45], 
                                  y=dat["dat_y"]$dat_y[1:45]), 
           width = 1, fill = "#00BFC4", stat = "identity") + 
  geom_line(data = cbind(dat["dat_x"], dat["dat_y"]), 
            aes(x=rep(x1,2), y=rep(equation(x1), 2)), colour = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=c(5.5, inv_equation(0.7), inv_equation(0.75), 5.5), 
                   y=c(0.7, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75)), fill = "purple") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

And the result is: [image]

Comment: Two more comments - (a) You should *never* use `data$col` inside `aes()`. It will work okay for simple plots, but will break with more complex ggplot features. `aes()` expects unquoted column names. You'd do better to modify your data frame then add different rows together inside `aes()`. (b) I think the visual result will look a little bit better if you put the line layer *on top* of the `geom_polygon` (just put it after `geom_polygon` in the code). (c) Since your just plotting a straight line, you might find `geom_abline` an easier interface. You can just give it a slope and an intercept.